# Android canvas split into two

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

I am developing a game in Android using Java in which the player plays alongside the computer. I need to split my canvas into two such that both the player and computer play the game on the same screen. Any ideas as to how this is done?

Answer (score 0):

Create two objects used to represent playing screens (you can add whatever you want here), and make a super class that holds the properties of their x-coordinate bounds.Then, in your android.view.View where you are holding the game, create an array of these objects (using the super class), loop through them in the onDraw function, and draw in those bounds based off of the information contained in the objects. If you could be more specific I would be more able to give you help pertaining to your game.These are just general guidelines.